# iOS8 UISplitViewController to always open primary controller on swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there a way in iOS8 to configure the `UISplitViewController` to always open the primary (master) controller when a swipe gesture is performed? Currently, if the detail controller is a navigation with some controllers already on stack then swiping (and also using `displayModeButtonItem`) will go to the previous controller on stack 'history'. I would like to leave that 'history' navigation to that button only and fix the swiping to always open the primary area (just like the drawer layout behaves in Android).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late and perhaps not what you're exactly looking for but you can just go `self.presentsWithGesture = true` in your split view controller. You can then just hide the navigation bar on the storyboard. 
[Here is a link showing you how to do that last part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965610/hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-9)