# Hide the status bar in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, statusbar

How do you hide the status bar in ios 9?

This is now deprecated:

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a status bar in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661031/how-to-hide-a-status-bar-in-ios)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Swift-3**

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}
```

I got the Information From [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732948/the-supportedinterfaceorientations-method-doesnt-override-any-method-from-its-s)

- Change `func` to `var`
- Delete `()`
- Change `->` to `:`

This works because a computed variable has a getter function, so the function you were implementing before simply turns into the getter function

---

2016 onwards: simple Thing like

On your info.plist add the following two property for statusBar Hidden

**View controller-based status bar appearance (Boolean: NO)**

**Status bar is initially hidden (Boolean: YES)**

By Source

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

**or**

[image]

---

Old answers ! ...

1. add `application.statusBarHidden` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   application.statusBarHidden = YES;
   return YES;
   }
   ```

and add

2. in `info.plist` add this `View controller-based status bar appearance` set `NO`

   ```
   View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
   ```

viewcontroller based hidden set

Add method in your view controller.

**Objective -C**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift upto 2**

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return true
}
```

(GOOD) 2016.5.17 in iOS 9.0 worked nicely.

**Updated Answer**

1. Go to Info.plist file
2. Hover on one of those lines and a (+) and (-) button will show up.
3. Click the plus button to add new key
4. Type in *start with capital V* and automatically the first choice will be **View controller-based status bar appearance**. Add that as the KEY.
5. Set the VALUE to "NO"
6. Go to you AppDelegate.m for Objective-C (*for swift language: AppDelegate.swift*)
7. Add the code, inside the method

---

**For Objective-C:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

---

**For Swift:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarHidden = true

    return true
}
```

Comment: @AshishKakkad -- I updated my answer, thanks a lot my friend

Comment: @AshishKakkad -- i am not face error iOS9, can u explain what are the errors,if I face its usefulor me

Comment: @AshishKakkad -- tanx my friend, in future if I face the issue , i surely use your answer

Comment: I don't think you want or need to add View controller-based status bar appearance = NO to you info.plist.  This will trigger an error message.  Adding the one line of code to your app delegate is sufficient for me.

Comment: application.statusBarHidden is deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: @JoeBlow - tanx buddy thats my old answer I updated answer verify once

Comment: "(GOOD) 2016.5.17 in iOS 9.0 worked nicely." - But it's not working on SDK 9.0.

Comment: Love your answer...perfectly collected.

Comment: @ajniN - happy to hear

Answer (score 16):

in info.plist add the following two property.

```
View controller-based status bar appearance (NO)

Status bar is initially hidden (YES)
```

Comment: Just overriding the preferredStatusBarHidden method did not work. Adding this finally did it for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is simply the correct and only answer for 2016+.  FINALLY apple fixed this idiotic problem.  Cheer!

Comment: hat tip to you.

Answer (score 7):

I know that the documentation of `setStatusBarHidden:` does not mention on what use instead. But the header of `UIApplication` does.

```
// Setting statusBarHidden does nothing if your application is using the default UIViewController-based status bar system.
@property(readwrite, nonatomic,getter=isStatusBarHidden) BOOL statusBarHidden NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]");
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_2, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]");
```

Here is stated that you should use the [`prefersStatusBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden) on `UIViewController` and use view controller based statusbar styles.

All you need to do now is configure whether the view controller needs to show of hide the status bar. Like so :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: But what if want to hide status bar on tap event of any button in VeiwController ?

Comment: @Mrug you might want to ask this question as a new topic and not a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how do you easily return a control over status bar visibility for **iOS 9+** and **Swift 3+**:

1. Add `View controller-based status bar appearance` key with `YES` value to `Info.plist`.
2. Add this variable to the view controller:

   ```
   private var isStatusBarHidden = false {
       didSet {
           setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Override `prefersStatusBarHidden` property:

   ```
   override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
       return isStatusBarHidden
   }
   ```

That's it. Now you are able to call `isStatusBarHidden = true` and `isStatusBarHidden = false` whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

An easy approach would be to set the `windowLevel` of the Application to be either normal or statusBar based on your needs, so to start

> **Objective-C**

**To Hide the Status Bar**

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
```

**To Show the Status Bar**

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
```

Also add the `Key` (**View controller-based status bar appearance**) with boolean value NO.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you need `View controller-based status bar appearance` equal to `YES` (for example to keep status bar white)

on AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method or wherever you setup your navigationController:

```
yourNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

then use [alex-staravoitau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735156/611879)'s awesome answer and add this code wherever you'll be hiding the status bar:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .lightContent
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve this result, but it worked for me and I hope it helps someone else too :)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. If you need fine control throughout the app this is the way to go. I didn't need to do anything in the AppDelegate though.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the iOS it will work. I have tested with iOS 10.

1. Open info.plist
2. "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to NO
3. "Status bar is initially hidden" set to YES
4. Done