# How to hide status bar for specific viewcontroller in ios 9, using objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I want to hide the status bar for specific view controllers, not for all.
then I tried this,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; in the `.AppDelegate.m` inside the `didfinishlaunchwithoption`  but it didn't work. and also it is deprecated.
```

then I tried in my viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

this also didn't work. anyone can help me with this.thnak you
**I don't want to use any deprecated methods here**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide the status bar in ios 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965610/hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-9)

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: nope bro @DianaProdan didn't work for me,tried all. do you have any idea.

Comment: I removed from .plist `'View controller-based status bar appearance` field, and added 
`- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}`
in controller where I need status bar to be hidden. It worked

Answer (score 1):

Go to info.plist and add two attributes if not present. set "Status bar is initially hidden" to "YES" and set "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" to "YES". This will hide status bar for your app.

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

and call this method where you want,For example from viewDidLoad

```
[self prefersStatusBarHidden];
```

Comment: this works fine for hide status bar. but it didn't work to show status bar in specific view controller.anyway thanx

Comment: @Graham check edited answer this is working perfect for me just change "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" to "YES" and do the other as same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below in your view controller.
Try the following method without deprication warnings:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Update for iOS 9

Add the following code in your viewController for hiding status bar.**

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `setStatusBarHidden(_:withAnimation:)` is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide the status bar for specific view controllers, not for all.

Only the *top-level* view controller gets to say whether the status bar is hidden. Your `prefersStatusBarHidden` is not consulted because your view controller is not the top-level view controller — it has some kind of parent view controller which is in charge of the status bar.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try below code in your view controller.

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]` this method is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Add below code to your view controller..

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

   return NO;
}
```

If you change the return value for this method, call the setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate method.

For childViewController, To specify that a child view controller should control preferred status bar hidden/unhidden state, implement the childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden method.

Comment: `prefersStatusBarHidden` not getting called

Comment: It's impossible to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` after return command in the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method.